# Download historical stock index data

Tags: python

I have the following data of stock index (NSE:NIFTY50) from google finance [here](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=207437&startdate=Jan%201%2C%201971&enddate=Jul%201%2C%202017&num=30&ei=mGBXWfnXKYim0gSDuovIBw&start=30).I want to download the above data as csv so that I can do some analysis on it. How do I download it.? I would prefer to use python if I can.

Comment: I'm surprised a user with your rep doesn't know how to ask a proper, complete question here. What have you tried ? (I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to download stock data using below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=207437&startdate=Jan%201%2C%201971&enddate=Jul%201%2C%202017&start={0}&num=30"
#change this to 138
how_many_pages=3
start=0

for i in range(how_many_pages):
    new_url = url.format(start)
    page = requests.get(new_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
    table = soup.find_all('table', class_='gf-table historical_price')[0] 

    columns_header = [th.getText() for th in table.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('th')]
    data_rows=table.findAll('tr')[1:]
    data=[[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll(['td'])] for i in range(len(data_rows))]

    if (start == 0):
        final_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns_header)
    else:
        df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns_header)
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df],axis=0)
    start += 30
#write your code to save final_df to csv
```

Pls don't forget to mark as answer if it helps :)

Comment: If I increase the number of pages to 4110 I get `File "nse_data.py", line 14, in <module>
    table = soup.find_all('table', class_='gf-table historical_price')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: change that to 138 (= 4110/30 +1)